# load expressionengine data dynamically

Tags: expressionengine

I'm trying to figure out how to get content dynamically from expression engine. Basically I have 6 article summaries as content. When the page loads, I'm getting 3 summaries, but I have a "show more" button. When it's clicked, I want to load the next 3 summaries but I don't know how to do this.

this is what my tags look like now:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blogposts" limit="3"}
    <div class='article-box'>
        <div class="article-image-box">
            <div class="article-image">

            </div>
        </div>
        <article>
            <h4>{title}</h4>
            <p class='author'>{blog_author}</p>
            <p>
                {blog_body}
            </p>
           <div class="ful-art-but-box">
                <button class="button green-but">
                    READ FULL ARTICLE
                </button>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your visitors to be able to "Load More" repeatedly as your content increase then Jelle's solution will not suffice.

To "future proof" it I would approach this by creating an EE template that returns entries in sets of three in JSON format, let's call it "more.json"

The "Load More" button would make an AJAX request to more.json.  It would need to specify an offset (the first time the button is hit it would need to return results 7 - 9 the next time it is hit it would need to return results 10 - 12 and so on).

You could pass the offset as a url segment like so:

```
your_template_group/more.json/6
```

The template more.json would take the value in the request segment_3 and pass this to the channel entries function, like so:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blogposts" limit="3" disable="" offset="segment_3"}
```

I'd use jQuery to handle the AJAX, append the results, update the button state etc.  There are many tutorials on this site and elsewhere explaining how to accomplish this.

Comment: hi thanks for the explanation, could you point me to a tutorial or two? I've been searching but can't find any. Maybe I'm using the wrong search keywords

Comment: Here's something that might get you started:  http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/loading-more-results-from-database

Answer (score 1):

First of all you will get better answers on the dedicated EE site at expressionengine.stackexchange.com

Why don't you just load all six entries, and hide the ones you don't want to display initially? then you can display them with javascript. This will also be better for performance.

```
    {exp:channel:entries channel="blogposts" limit="6" disable=""}
{if count == 3}
    <div class="hidden">
{/if}
        <div class='article-box'>
            <div class="article-image-box">
                <div class="article-image">
                </div>
            </div>
            <article>
                <h4>{title}</h4>
                <p class='author'>{blog_author}</p>
                <p>
                    {blog_body}
                </p>
               <div class="ful-art-but-box">
                    <button class="button green-but">
                        READ FULL ARTICLE
                    </button>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
{if total_results == "0"}
    </div>
{/if} 
    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: I think this will work for now because I don't need to make it future-proof since its a test project at the moment

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Jelle Dijkstra: "First of all you will get better answers on the dedicated EE site at expressionengine.stackexchange.com"

That said, why not keep it simple and just use the jQuery "load" method?

You can read up on it here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp
or here: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Basically, just add a link/button that has a click event. On the click event, load a template that pulls in the info you need. You could even do a single entry sample in your template, and then feed it variables for "start_on" or "limit" to make it even more dynamic based on user selection, screen size, or for you to use in other areas as well. Using load also allows you to have a "callback" function so that you can have a "loading" icon display until the content is delivered.

This, to me would be the simplest of ways.  ;)